# Change a Text Field Fill Color

Tags: c#, fastreport

How do I change the fill color of text component?

I've tried something like this:

```
Text1.Fill = Color.Black;
Text2.Fill = Color.White;
```

Manual is no help either.

It gives out the following error:

```
    Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'FastReport.FillBase' 
(39,39): Error CS0117: 'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a definition for 'white' 
(43,28): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'FastReport.FillBase'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bit more context needed. What do you mean by a "text component" for a start? What happens when you run the code above?

Comment: Right, so it's a simple type conversion error. You can't set that property to a `Color` type of object because the property is of the type `FastReport.FillBase` - you need to use an object of that type instead. Intellisense should have told you what type of object to use?

Comment: @ADyson, The thing is that I use a web-nested version for my platform and Intellisense doesn't work there for some reason. That's why it's so complicated to find these things out. I've tried going Text1.Fill.Color = Color.White. No success. It says that there's no definition for Color

Comment: What do you mean by a "web-nested version"?? If you included the DLL for this library in your project you should get intellisense. Anyway, even if you don't, the error makes it fairly clear what to do - you need to set the property's value as a FillBase type of object, because that's what type the "Fill" property is defined as. Presumably the manual tells you about the FillBase type, even if intellisense doesn't.

Comment: "I've tried going Text1.Fill.Color = Color.White. No success. It says that there's no definition for Color" ...no, it says there's no definition for Color.**white** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx shows you the possible values, and white is not one of them. White is though (case-sensitive). Anyway it's completely irrelevant because you can't set this property to be a Color object, as I already mentioned. Do you understand about different types of object?

Comment: @ADyson I do understand the difference. It's more of a 'go-searching' kind of question. Color.White does exist there by the way. The equestion is then what type is there to use for it? If it's not fill. FillBase itselft is not defined. Text1...what does go next? Or maybe I'm just stupid...I've just started using this fastreport thing so I don't know exactly what are the types that're supported in this case.

Comment: "Color.White does exist there by the way. ". I know. Read my comment again. Color.white doesn't, and that's what the error message told you. Case-sensitive, like I said,

Comment: "FillBase itselft is not defined. "...so you can't do `FastReport.FillBase x = new FastReport.FillBase();`? Or perhaps it's an enum where you can choose a colour? Doesn't the Class Reference documentation tell you what this object is? (I can't download it without registering). Or perhaps you have to use a different property like the answer below suggests. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Text1.FillColor = Color.Black;
```

if "Text1" is a TextObject, this should work.

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled upon it yesterday by myself. Still thanks.